# Terraform local-exec command scp fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, scp

I am trying to copy directory to new ec2 instance using terraform

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r ../ansible ubuntu@${self.public_ip}:~/playbook_dir"
}
```

But after instance created I get an error

```
Error running command 'sleep 5; scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o
│ UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r ../ansible ubuntu@54.93.82.73:~/playbook_dir': exit status 1. Output:
│ ssh: connect to host 54.93.82.73 port 22: Connection refused
│ lost connection
```

The main thing is that if I copy command to terminal and replace IP it works. Why is that happens? Please, help to figure out

I read in documentation that sshd service may not work correctly right after creating, so I added sleep 5 command before scp, but it haven't work

Comment: Ypu can try with the full path to the file.

Comment: @MarkoE that doesn't work

Comment: Have you defined the security group rules properly to allow SSH access?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same in my local env, but unfortunately, when using the `local-exec` provisioner in `aws_instance` directly I also got the same error message and am honestly not sure of the details of it.

However, to workaround the issue you can use a `null_resource` with the `local-exec` provisioner with the same command including sleep and it works.

### Terraform code

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}
resource "aws_key_pair" "stackoverflow" {
  key_name   = "stackoverflow-key"
  public_key = "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIKml4tkIVsa1JSZ0OSqSBnF+0rTMWC5y7it4y4F/cMz6"
}
resource "aws_instance" "stackoverflow" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids ## Must allow SSH inbound
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.stackoverflow.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = "stackoverflow"
  }

}

resource "aws_eip" "stackoverflow" {
  instance = aws_instance.stackoverflow.id
  vpc      = true
}

output "public_ip" {
  value = aws_eip.stackoverflow.public_ip
}

resource "null_resource" "scp" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "sleep 10 ;scp -i ~/.ssh/aws-stackoverflow  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r ~/test/sub-test-dir ubuntu@${aws_eip.stackoverflow.public_ip}:~/playbook_dir"
  }
}
```

### Code In Action

```bash
aws_key_pair.stackoverflow: Creating...
aws_key_pair.stackoverflow: Creation complete after 0s [id=stackoverflow-key]
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Creating...
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_instance.stackoverflow: Creation complete after 42s [id=i-006c17b995b9b7bd6]
aws_eip.stackoverflow: Creating...
aws_eip.stackoverflow: Creation complete after 1s [id=eipalloc-0019932a06ccbb425]
null_resource.scp: Creating...
null_resource.scp: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.scp (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "sleep 10 ;scp -i ~/.ssh/aws-stackoverflow  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r ~/test/sub-test-dir ubuntu@3.76.153.108:~/playbook_dir"]
null_resource.scp: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
null_resource.scp (local-exec): Warning: Permanently added '3.76.153.108' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
null_resource.scp: Creation complete after 13s [id=3541365434265352801]
```

### Verification Process

- Local directory and files

```bash
$ ls  ~/test/sub-test-dir                                                                                               
some_test_file
$ cat  ~/test/sub-test-dir/some_test_file                                                                               
local exec is not nice !!
```

- Files and directory on Created instance

```bash
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-stackoverflow ubuntu@$(terraform output -raw public_ip)                                             
The authenticity of host '3.76.153.108 (3.76.153.108)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:8dgDXB/wjePQ+HkRC61hTNnwaSBQetcQ/10E5HLZSwc.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '3.76.153.108' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1028-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sat Feb 11 00:25:13 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.0               Processes:             98
  Usage of /:   20.8% of 7.57GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 24%               IPv4 address for eth0: 172.31.6.219
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Ubuntu Pro delivers the most comprehensive open source security and
   compliance features.

   https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro

 * Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications.
   Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your
   Ubuntu Pro subscription. Free for personal use.

     https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status


To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-219:~$ cat ~/playbook_dir/some_test_file 
local exec is not nice !!
```

Comment: That doesn't solve a problem in y case, i'm afraid

Comment: Is it still the same error message? and could you please confirm that your security group associated with this instance allows SSH(port 22) from at least the machine from which this code is executed?