# scp in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm trying to scp a folder from my MacOS local machine to Ubuntu EC2 instance using Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This block should parse instance DNS name from terraform output
terraform apply -auto-approve | tee output.txt
publicdns=$(grep 'instance_dns_name = "' output.txt | cut -b 26-)
public_dns_name=${publicdns%?}
echo $public_dns_name # I added this to show that DNS name in variable is correct

scp -v -r -i ~/dev_folder/test_task_tf/tf_key.pem ~/dev_folder/test_task_tf/docker_dir ubuntu@$public_dns_name:~/
```

Terminal output:

```
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ecx-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com, user ubuntu, command sftp
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/maxivanov/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/\* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for \*
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
```

The 22 port is open in my security group, all ways to files is OK, because when I'm trying to do scp without Bash script I have no errors.

Help me, please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested to login manually using ssh ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com ? 

I think the problem is in your /etc/ssh/ssh_config file. But should be good to know if if manualy works. Might also be that port 22 is blocked

Comment: Add more `v` to the scp command for more verbosity/debug  (e.g. `scp -vvv ...`), also, run the script with `bash -x <script.sh>` and see if there is anything that stands out. Also, lookout for tilde expansion as I think that would happen before sending the code, so the tilde `~` would be replaced with your local home dir, and if it doesn't exist on the destination, might be causing some issues.

Comment: The error "ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused" pretty clearly indicates some sort of network (firewall/address/port) problem. Running in a script should not affect this, so I'd look elsewhere for causes. When it works (outside of the script), are you running it *exactly* the same way it's being run in the script? Also, does the server have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses? If so, one might be working and the other failing.

Comment: > the comment is not a direct answer but is related to a similar issue.

please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75416333/terraform-local-exec-command-scp-fails/75417339#75417339 if it helps. 

I would also prefer `BASH_VAR=$(terraform output <output_defined_in_code> -raw)`  but that's not the issue here, it's just something additional to mention.